# Throwing an exception from an inherited function without throws

Tags: swift, exception

I'm trying to do the following:

```
protocol X{
    func foo()
}
enum XError{
    case BAR
}
class Y:X{
    func foo(){
        throw XError.BAR
    }
}
```

I can't add a throws declaration to the protocol and it complains that

> the error is not handled because the enclosing function is not
>   declared 'throws'.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to explicitly add throw in the signature of any function that throws.

So

```
func foo() throws {
    throw XError.BAR
}
```

This also applies to the protocol definition.

```
protocol X {
    func foo() throws
}
```

Errors in Swift should conform to the `Error` protocol.

```
enum XError: Error {
    case BAR
}
```

Comment: so if I inherit the method signature without throws from a protocol I have no control over I cannot throw an exception?

Comment: No since any code using instances of the protocol is not using `try` or handling any exceptions.

Comment: So if I add throws to my method signature it stops conforming to the protocol and if I don't I can't have proper exception handling... is this some sort of limitation of the language? Is there a way to cope with this?

Comment: Yes exactly, if you can't change the protocol you need to make sure you handle any problems in some other way. It's a limitation of the language, but that is also how it has to work. Imagine if I have an instance of `X` and call `foo` on it. If foo doesn't have `throws` in the signature I can't know that it throws and I can't handle any exceptions.

Comment: Can't you just catch all exceptions like in a fault tolerance case where you don't actually know what if coming out of a faulty function? But I understand that his limit increases the language safety as a tradeoff from flexibility.

Comment: Yes the tradeoff made in Swift is that nothing can throw unless explicitly marked. This fits the overall strictness of the language very well, but it also makes some cases a bit difficult.